# Recursive power calculation

Tags: c#, factorial

I need to write a recursive method `Power(base, exponent)` that, when called, returns `Power(3,4) = 3*3*3*3`. And `exponent` is an integer greater than or equal to 1. Below is my code, but it is wrong. I want to use factorial, but i know little about factorial.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("please enter base,\n" + "please enter exponent,\n" + "pressing 'Enter'after each one");

    double number1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    int number2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    double result = Pow(number1, number2);

    Console.WriteLine("pow({0},{1}) is {2}",number1,number2,result);
}

public static long Factorial(long number)
{
    if (number <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return number * Factorial(number - 1);
}

public static double Pow(double basevalue, int exponentvalue)
{
    double a=1;
    if (exponentvalue==1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is not make sense!");
        return basevalue;
    }
    else if(exponentvalue > 1)
    {
        a=exponentvalue * Factorial(exponentvalue - 1);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a factorial is?

Comment: Why are you talking about factorial to calculated powers? That makes no sense.

Comment: And by the way: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you haven't done it already, I suggest that you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq]).

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the reason you talk about factorial is because it can be computed using a recursive algorithm and so can computing the integer power of a number. Other than that you should not use factorial to compute the power.

To compute the power of a number using recursion you can do it like this:

```
Power(base, exponent) = base*Power(base, exponent - 1)
```

and to terminate the recursion:

```
Power(base, 0) = 1
```

Computing `Power(3, 4)` using recursion evaluates to this:

```
Power(3, 4)
    = 3*Power(3, 3)
    = 3*3*Power(3, 2)
    = 3*3*3*Power(3, 1)
    = 3*3*3*3*Power(3, 0)
    = 3*3*3*3*1
```

Implementing this in C# is left as an exercise.

Comment: Heh heh, guess I kinda spoiled the exercise...

Answer (score 2):

Easy. You can throw in some extra checks for invalid `exponentvalue` if you want.

```
public static double Pow(double basevalue, int exponentvalue)
{
    if (exponentvalue == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (exponentvalue == 1)
    {
        return baseValue;
    }
    return baseValue * Pow(basevalue, exponentvalue-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to look up some of the functions you are using mate. Factorials have got **nothing** to do with powers. You can write a power as a recursive function as such:

```
internal static double Pow(double @base, int exponent)
{
    if (exponent < 0)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Usage of this function is limited to positive exponents only");
        throw new Exception();
    }
    else if (exponent == 1)
    {
        return @base;
    }
    else if (exponent == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return @base * Pow(@base, exponent - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Speak for yourself.

Comment: Well clarity part is a question of personal point of view (no need to be rude). The "redundancy" part is not an opinion, it's a fact.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I actually added it to be more explicit, as in: "if none of the above conditions are true, **only** then, return x", as opposed to leaving the else out (it'll compile to the same CIL anyway). Secondly, "don't  use else with return statements" is just as imperative as "speak for yourself", so I don't quite understand how I'm suddenly rude.

Comment: For the last point, you're right, sorry ;) I'm still not ok with the "clarity", but... that's kind of personal.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Well let's agree to disagree on that one then (or edit the answer if you really want to make a point ;) ).